# Is this question now off topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question a number of years ago:

[What is the best way to integrate with quickbooks from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083744/what-is-the-best-way-to-integrate-with-quickbooks-from-c-sharp-code)

From time to time while I'm looking over my profile I click into it and I find my self thinking: This appears to be off topic since I'm asking for an off site resource of a library.  But then I think, no its on topic because I'm really asking for general guidance.

Then I got to thinking, I'm sure other questions fall into this "problem" and wanted to know how to handle them.

Thoughts?

Comment: yep voted to close.

Comment: [The times, they are a changin'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7qQ6_RV4VQ). I can see several reasons why it would be off-topic by today's standards: too broad, opinion-based. But multiple upvotes on several answers...I would leave it. Though, not it will probably die to the meta effect.

Comment: Unquestionably off-topic today. I note that the question and all the answers are some three years old which suggests that it's probably out of date. Vote to close, definitely.